# change header color of Dataframe with multi level header and save it to excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a Pandas DataFrame with multi level header like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szU1M.png)

I would like to export this in excel with change header color and put all in frame. I tried all openpyxl, xlsxwriter, ... but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can archieve this by using openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl as px
from openpyxl import styles
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side

newFile = r'yourFile.xlsx'

wb = px.load_workbook(newFile)
ws = wb.active

cols = ws.max_column

greyFill = styles.PatternFill(start_color='00808080',
           end_color='00808080',
           fill_type='solid')

thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'), 
                     right=Side(style='thin'), 
                     top=Side(style='thin'), 
                     bottom=Side(style='thin'))

for col in range(2, cols+1):
    for row in range(1,4):
        
        if ws.cell(row, col).value:
            ws.cell(row, col).fill = greyFill
            ws.cell(row, col).border = thin_border

#ws['B1':'H3'].border = thin_border
wb.save(newFile)
```